# routerLink in angular 2 displays as a plain text

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have been facing an issue with routerLink in angular 2.
I'm working with Visual Studio 2015, trying to create a SPA with routing concept.
On click of anchor tag with [routerLink], it should redirect me to a specific page, but the anchor tag is not clickable - it appears as plain text.

**MasterPage.html-**

```
Left menu headers footers
<a [routerLink]="['Supplier']">Supplier</a> 
<a [routerLink]="['Customer']">Customer</a><br />
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Routing.ts -**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CustomerComponent} from '../Binder/CustomerComponent';
import {SupplierComponent} from "../Binder/SupplierComponent";

export const ApplicationRoutes = [
{ path: 'Customer', component: CustomerComponent },
{ path: 'Supplier', component: SupplierComponent }
];
```

**app.module-**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CustomerComponent }   from './CustomerComponent';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms"
import {GridComponent} from "./GridComponent"
import { MasterPageComponent }   from './MasterPageComponent';
import { SupplierComponent }   from './SupplierComponent';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ApplicationRoutes } from './Routing';

@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(ApplicationRoutes),
BrowserModule,
FormsModule],
declarations: [
CustomerComponent,
SupplierComponent,                  
MasterPageComponent],
bootstrap: [MasterPageComponent]
})
export class MainModuleLibrary { }
```

Please let me know if you need any more details from me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try without brackets: `<a routerLink="Supplier">Supplier</a> ` Perhaps add a slahs in front of `Supplier` as well => `"/Supplier"`

Comment: Where's does this link direct to - `'../Binder/CustomerComponent'`? Is it a folder or `Binder` is a folder with two components? `CustomerComponent` and `SupplierComponent`?

Comment: @LavanyaM, I updated my answer, just to make sure that you have everything present in your code that needs to be.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <a routerLink="/Supplier" routerLinkActive="active">Supplier</a>
  <a routerLink="/Customer" routerLinkActive="active">Customer</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

EDIT: You have indeed also the line similar to this in your routing.ts file?

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(ApplicatonRoutes);
```

and have imported that to your `@ngModule`, right? Not knowing your project, if you are just starting it, and having no "real content" means that this will show the links on your page, and they are not clickable, and produces no error.

Comment: I have added app.module in the question, which contains the above line which you have mentioned.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I guess the only thing you can do at this time, is to try and reproduce a plunker...

Answer (score 0):

**`MasterPage.html`**

```
<a [routerLink]="['./Supplier']">Supplier</a> 
<a [routerLink]="['./Customer']">Customer</a><br />
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**`Routing.ts`**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerComponent } from '../Binder/CustomerComponent';
import { SupplierComponent } from '../Binder/SupplierComponent';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: 'Customer', component: CustomerComponent },
   { path: 'Supplier', component: SupplierComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**`app.module`**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CustomerComponent }   from './CustomerComponent';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms"
import { GridComponent } from "./GridComponent"
import { MasterPageComponent }   from './MasterPageComponent';
import { SupplierComponent }   from './SupplierComponent';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routing } from './Routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    routing,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule],
  declarations: [
    CustomerComponent,
    SupplierComponent,                  
    MasterPageComponent],
  bootstrap: [MasterPageComponent]
})
export class MainModuleLibrary { }
```

And by the way, avoid capitalizing your files, aswell as the routes.

Comment: Not working :(. Binder is a folder with 2 components.

Comment: Show your `app.module` file.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your link with a slash :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Supplier']">Supplier</a> 
<a [routerLink]="['/Customer']">Customer</a><br />
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the missing import of `RouterModule` in the module, where I was using the `routerLink` directive.

```js
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //...
  ],
  imports: [
    //...
    RouterModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    //...
  ]
})
```